# Is there a name for a position on a function surface and the value at that position?

Tags: functions, terminology

Is there a name for a position on a function surface and the value at that position?
E.g., if I have the function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$, and I know that at the point $(2, 2)$ it evaluates to $8$, is there a name for the data structure $(2, 2, 8)$ [which is in this example $(x, y, f(x, y))$]?

Comment: This doesn't quite answer your question, but the set of all points of the form $(x,y,f(x,y))$ is called the graph of the function $f$, so in your case, $(2,2,8)$ is a point in the graph. In general, for any function $f : X \to Y$ between two sets, the set $\{ (x,f(x)) \mid x \in X \} \subseteq X \times Y$ is the graph of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an element of  [the graph of $f$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function). The formal definition of the graph of a function $f:X\to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are any two sets, is the subset $\Gamma(f)\subset X\times Y$ consisting of 
$$\Gamma(f)=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y\mid y=f(x)\}.$$
So, in your case, $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ is the plane, $Y=\mathbb{R}$ is the real numbers, and
$$\Gamma(f)=\{((x,y),z)\in \mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}\mid z=f(x,y)\}.$$
But we usually identify $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}^3$, of course, and we get
$$\Gamma(f)=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\mid z=f(x,y)\},$$
or in other words, $\Gamma(f)$ consists of the triples $(x,y,f(x,y))$, such as $(2,2,8)$.

Comment: Thanks. I am guessing there is no fancy name for "element of the graph of f"?

Comment: No, I don't believe so.